# jQuery hover function inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a problem in my jQuery code, when a dropdown toggle have data-toggle = 'hover' should show the sub menu when hovered, and if this toggle have data-toggle = 'dropdown' should only show the sub menu when clicked.
The code seems to work but when the window is resized and the attribute is changed FROM HOVER TO DROPDOWN (the other way seems to work just fine) the hover function still execute anyway.

Here's the code

```
function main() {
    if (($('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle'))=='hover') {
        $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
            $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
            $(this).addClass('open');
          }, function() {
            $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
            $(this).removeClass('open');
          });
       }
      }
      $(document).ready(main);
      $(window).resize(main);
```

and the attribute changement function

```
function clickEvent() {
    if(viewport().width <= 991) {
        $('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
    } else {
        $('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle','hover');
    }
}
$(document).ready(clickEvent);
$(window).resize(clickEvent);
```

Comment: You've set things up so that you call `main()` from the "resize" event - that will add new event handlers via `.hover()` each time you call it. Those jQuery event handler APIs never *replace* prior handlers, they always add *new* handlers on top of the old ones, even if they're exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a blocking condition inside of the event handler,

```
function main() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        if ($('a.dropdown-toggle').data('toggle')!=='hover') { return; }
        $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(100);
        $(this).addClass('open');
      }, function() {
        if ($('a.dropdown-toggle').data('toggle')!=='hover') { return; }
        $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
}
```

or better do some tweaking in the event binding,

```
//remove the if statement inside of main function and do the below.

function clickEvent() {
    if(viewport().width <= 991) {
        $('.dropdown').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
    } else {
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should elaborate as to why the OP should do that

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can just be more specific with your selector and do away with the `if` statement entirely.

Try using the following selector:

```
a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="hover"]
```

---

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        //This function will execute when the dropdown-toggle is set to Hover
        //and the mouse is hovering over the element
        //some code like $(this).slideDown(100)
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        //And this function will run after the the mouse leaves the selector element
    }
}, 'a.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle="hover"]');
```

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your resize and ready functions. But you shouldn't need them.